# Iterating through table cells using jQuery and appending to div

Tags: jquery, html-table, iteration

I am really confused here..
I am trying to get the values from a table and add those values to the div  with class title using 
append function and `.text` function.
The problem is that when I use the each function the last value in table gets appended and 
the rest are skipped..
This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#nameGridView tr').each(function() {
            if (!this.rowIndex) return; // skip first row
            var productName = this.cells[0].innerHTML;
            $('.title').each(function (i, obj) {
                $('.title').html(productName);

            });

        });
    });

</script>
```

Please tell me how to iterate through each table and add simultaneously, like say for first div title, the first value from table gets appended and so on. 
thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) to append to an element. Also use `.eq()` to get the div with the same index as the row.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var $title = $('.title');
        $('#nameGridView tr').each(function(i) {
            if (!this.rowIndex) return; // skip first row
            var productName = this.cells[0].innerHTML;
            $title.eq(i-1).append(productName);            
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: well there are many divs. the same divs as the rows cells in the table to append to... please!! help me.. i really need this...

Comment: i wish i could give you credits here but i am am a newbie and my points are low so i cant but as soon as i have i will definately do it..:)

Comment: @RyanComputerProgrammer to give credit you can accept this as the answer by clicking the tick next to the answer.